# php specify file content convert

Tags: php, arrays, file

Is it possible to convert specific text file content into a php array ?

For example:

**Text file**

```
//group
1
// first id other values
1 5 7 3 83 83 83 1
2 6 7 3 86 83 83 4
3 3 7 3 63 83 83 7
4 3 7 3 84 83 86 1
end
//group
2
// first id other values
1 3 7 3 83 83 83 1
2 6 7 3 86 83 83 4
3 3 7 3 63 83 83 7
4 3 7 3 84 83 86 1
end
```

**Return php array**

```
1 => array(
  1 => array(5, 7, 3, 83, 83, 83, 1),
  2 => array...
),
2 => array(
  1 => array(3, ...),
  ....
```

and so on, until end then next number group, and also ignore comments lines **//** or **#**

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: i think you can use `file_get_contents` to get the data from the file.. `explode` it using `\n` and then put each line into an array... and about `//` and `#`, you can use `preg_replace` to replace them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved...

**Text file**

```
// group 1
1
1 4 3 "ssssssss"
end

// group 2
2
1 5 4 "ssssssss s"
end

// group 3
3
1 6 5 "ssssssss ss"
end
```

**php convert code**

```
$list = array();
$handle = fopen('Item.txt', 'r');

while(($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
{

    // skip comments
    if(preg_match('!^//!', $line) || preg_match('/#/', $line))
    {

        continue;

    }

    // replace all spaces
    $line = preg_replace('~"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|\s+~', ',', $line);

    // skip blanks
    if($line[0] == ',')
    {

        continue;

    }

    // define group
    if(substr_count($line, ',') == 1 || substr_count($line, 'end') == 1)
    {

        if(substr_count($line, 'end') == 0)
        {

            $key = str_replace(',', '', $line);

        }

        continue;

    }

    // remove last comma
    if(substr($line, -1) == ',')
    {

        $line = substr($line, 0, -1);

    }

    $arguments = explode(',', $line);

    $id = $arguments[0];

    unset($arguments[0]);

    $list[$key][$id] = $arguments;



}

fclose($handle);
print_r($list);
```

output http://prntscr.com/6emxpq

Answer (score 1):

I've got another solution:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');
$string = "//group
            1
            // first id other values
            1 5 7 3 83 83 83 1
            2 6 7 3 86 83 83 4
            3 3 7 3 63 83 83 7
            4 3 7 3 84 83 86 1
            end
            //group
            2
            // first id other values
            1 3 7 3 83 83 83 1
            2 6 7 3 86 83 83 4
            3 3 7 3 63 83 83 7
            4 3 7 3 84 83 86 2
            end";

$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9 \n]/','',$string);

$array = array_filter(explode("\n", $string));
$temp_array = array();
$new_array = array();
$index = -1;
foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    if(strlen(trim($arr)) == 1 && intval($arr) > 0){
        $index = intval($arr);
    }
    else if(strlen(trim($arr)) > 4){
        $temp_array = array_values(array_filter(explode(" ", $arr)));
        $temp_index = $temp_array[0];
        unset($temp_array[0]);
        $new_array[$index][$temp_index] = $temp_array;        
    }
}

print_r(array_filter($new_array));

?>
```

Comment: well next time be more specific.. I just showed you that it is possible to make parsing with the input you have posted!